# Multiple react-native instances in a single app causes touch event problems

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jitsi

I have the following setup: My app is a react-native app and one of its views is a custom native component that renders `RCTRootView` for ios and `ReactRootView` for android and actually loads another react-native instance with another js bundle. This other react native app is actually Jitsi mobile sdks. These native react views are instantiated with separate from the root app `RCTBridge` for iOS and `ReactInstanceManager` for android.

This setup is working OK, but I have the following issue. Sometimes touch events for touchables in Jitsi part of the app (the other encapsulated react-native instance) trigger random `onPress` callbacks in my root app. I logged the events on both ends and found out that they have a `target` with the same node identifier. So both react-native instances have views with the same react node identifiers which is understandable since they are instantiated with separate `RCTBridge` and `ReactInstanceManager`. The problem seems to be that the native touch events are passed to both react-native instances although they are generated over the views of just one of them. Does anyone have an idea how I could separate this event handling?

I was also considering that I may be able to fix the issue if I just use single `ReactInstanceManager` and `RCTBridge`, so the views don't have duplicate node identifiers, but loading multiple js bundles seems to be a feature that is still under development. If someone can give me directions about loading multiple js bundles in a single react-native app, will also be of help :)

Thanks!